# bastille linux command line pass config file with answers

Tags: linux

I have bastille for hardening and Im using it as follows

```
    /usr/sbin/bastille -c
```

The above starts it in interactive mode

Is it possible to provide bastille linux set of answers via a file on the command line? If yes, an example would be helpful. Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the fine manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/bastille.1m.html), copying the config you want into `/etc/Bastille/config` and then running `bastille -b` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank You womble .... in future ill be sure to RTM carefully before posting qs to the community ... appreciate your help and guidance....